# Need formula to split the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have (500+rows 20+ columns) sheet and some cells having data as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify: every cell has 3 rows? And at the end of each row within a cell, is there a newline character? Or is it just formatting makes it look like 3 rows? Also, if you consider VBA answers, please update your tags.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text into columns do something like this

[image]

Enter this formula to extract first line

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1,1)-1)
```

to extract middle line

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1) + 1, SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1,SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1)+1) - SEARCH(CHAR(10),A1) - 1)
```

to extract last line

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - SEARCH(CHAR(10), A1, SEARCH(CHAR(10), A1) + 1))
```

Answer (score -2):

Select Column A

Go to Ribbon

Data -> Text to Columns

- check "Delimited", click Next
- check "Other", enter the character "/" in the box next to Other:
- click Finish

Comment: Nope, it will not work because there is no delimited in cell.

Comment: This won't give the desired outcome as the question asks.